# How/when to query 'extended' entities in Breeze

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application

I have a ViewModel that loads up 'child' entities and I want to also display 'grandchild' entities based off of each child that is loaded.  To simplify things, I need help identifying how to query these objects and display them under the proper 'tree' in the browser (apologies for my butchering of coding language : ))

I am using Knockout to bind the data and loading up the entities with Breeze.  This question is an extension of [When to add extend additional complex types onto a Breeze entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196861/when-to-add-extend-additional-complex-types-onto-a-breeze-entity)

Also - my model is EF code first and I have a configuration defining a one to many relationship between children and grandchildren, and I *think* Breeze knows this already but I am trying to figure out how to take advantage of this.

childs.js (view model)

```
var childs = ko.observableArray();
var grandChilds = ko.observableArray();
var parentId = ko.observable();

function refresh() {
    var parentId = (parent).parentId;  // << for ex. don't worry about this line : )
    return Q.all([getChildren(), getGrandChildren()]);
}

function getChildren() {
    return datacontext.getChildren(childs, parentId);
}

function getGrandChildren() {
    return datacontext.getGrandChildren(grandChilds);
}
```

and in the view (childs.html)

```
<div data-bind="foreach: childs">
    <div title="Go to Child Details">
        <div><strong data-bind="text: name"></strong></div>
        <div><strong data-bind="text: gender().description"></strong></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- ko.compose { view: grandChilds} --><!--/ko-->
    </div>
</div>
```

And my current datacontext for reference

```
    var getChilds= function (childsObservable, parentId) {

        var query = EntityQuery.from('Childs')
            .where('parentId', '==', parentId)
            .expand('grandChildren')
            .orderBy('id');

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (childsObservable) {
                childsObservable(data.results);
            }
            logger.log('Retrieved [Childs] and [Grandchilds] from remote data source', data, system.getModuleId(datacontext), true);
        }
    };
```

I want to load up only grandchildren of the children, and since there are many children I want to only display grandchildren under the correct child, not all grandchildren in one list.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a note Jay left me a note on my other question to look into the EntityQuery.expand method and I am re-reading it now and am pretty sure the answer lies here and I should have researched this before opening a new question, but feel free to make me feel stupid for not doing so : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three basic approaches to querying and "linking" related entities.

1) Use *EntityQuery.expand*

2) Use *EntityAspect.loadNavigationProperty*

3) Create a "broad" EntityQuery that just happens to encompass the entire graph and all of the   parent/child relations will be automatically linked.

Comment: Thanks Jay I forgot all about the expand method.  I was able to easily load up all entities and match them up properly.  It's one of those "you don't know what you don't know" things, Breeze makes it so easy sometimes we look for antiquated ways to fix easy problems.